# Copy files with renaming

Tags: rename, file-copy

I have a huge file tree. Some files have same name but in different case, e.g., `some_code.c` and `Some_Code.c`.

So when I'm trying to copy it to an NTFS/FAT filesystem, it asks me about whether I want it to replace the file or skip it.

Is there any way to automatically rename such files, for example, by adding  `(1)` to the name of conflict file (as Windows 7 does)?

Comment: Curious. I just wanted to see, what kind of error I get if I try to produce a file with the same name on a NTFS-partition (HPFS/NTFS, according to `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`), and did `touch foo; touch Foo` and ended with 2 files `foo` and `Foo`. But I'm not curious enogh to reboot into Windows, to look how they look like over there. Migth it just be a FAT-problem? Ah - I have an USB-Stick with FAT, and could create a FAT-system inside a file, ... - one moment please. :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Many GNU tools such as `cp`, `mv` and `tar` support creating backup files when the target exists. That is, when copying `foo` to `bar`, if there is already a file called `bar`, the *existing* `bar` will be renamed, and after the copy `bar` will contain the contents of `foo`. By default, `bar` is renamed to `bar~`, but the behavior can be modified:

```
                                # If a file foo exists in the target, then…
cp -r --backup source target    #   rename foo → foo~
cp -r --backup=t source target  #   rename foo → foo.~1~ (or foo.~2~, etc)
```

There are other variants, such as creating numbered backups only when one already exists. See the [coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Backup-options) for more details.

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know this option existed, and it just proved to be extremely useful. Thanks @Gilles.

Comment: OSX cp does not have --backup flag. use `brew install coreutils` and then use the command `gcp` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I tried

```
apropos copy | grep "(1)"
```

to find possible candidates, and mcopy showed up.

```
man mcopy
```

shows a promising option `-D clash-option` isn't that cool? But not so cool - it isn't described. But there are some hints to mtools.dvi, which I searched on my system, without success, and via google, without success, but then, with google, I searched directly for `mcopy clash-option` and [found this site](http://www.dcn.ryerson.ca/floppy/mtools_doc/mtools_2.html#SEC6).

I made a short test

```
mcopy -D A f* a
```

to tests for autorename and targetdir `a` - instead of autorenaming it asked me for every file to ignore or override, that stupid s... .

My version is `mtools-4.0.10` and the help page is from 1996 - 15 years old. Should we really lost some features, meanwhile?

I would split the work into two steps:

- Make a short function, which generates a unique name for a file, if that name is occupied.
- Run `find`, and execute that script for every file you wish to copy.

Shall we assist in this approach? :)

Here is a script, to autorename files:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
target=$2

autorename () {
name=$1
target=$2
no=$3 

test -e ${target}/${name}.$no && autorename ${name} ${target} $((no+1)) || cp ${name} ${target}/${name}.$no 

}

test -e ${target}/${name} && autorename ${name} ${target} 0 || cp ${name} ${target}
```

and this is my test invocation:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "fo*" -type f -exec ./autorename.sh {} /mnt/hidden/test/a ";"
```

Note: -maxdepth, -name and -type where used to restrict the number of affected files dramatically. 
I didn't test the script for deeper file structures, nor for blanks in filenames and other, funky characters like linefeed, pagefeed and so on.

I used .1 because it doesn't make trouble in most commands, while a ( and a ) often need masking.

Comment: [WayBack Machine archive of site at link given, for mtools v3](http://web.archive.org/web/20041227062153/http://www.dcn.ryerson.ca/floppy/mtools_doc/mtools_2.html). Other live versions (identical for mtools v4.0.18) at http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html and http://www.mtools.linux.lu/mtools.html

Answer (score 0):

Not with GNU `cp`, at least.

You are strongly advised to not have duplicate file names (ignoring case), they will just cause you a world of pain.  Find a list of such duplicates using

```
find . | tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -d
```

Then manually rename one of the files for each line if output.  Try to avoid creating duplicates in future.

Comment: The guy never implied that he's the one who created that mess.

Comment: Well, yes, true, but he is the one suffering the consequences ☺

Comment: I have a situation where I ended up with backups from slightly different times. Want to combine them, but not clobber different versions. For instance, for all I know, the older one might be better. Can only tell after I examine. In the mean time, need to copy and rename backups.

Comment: That's only feasible for human created files, like source code. In my case, I have a bunch of automatically generated files with the same name, because using different names would be even messier. But now I ended up needing to merge all these files, or at least put them in the same directory.

Comment: well the point of the question is to prevent these messes from happening